# How to get RecyclerView's child from integer value?

Tags: java, android

How can I get List Items in RecyclerList using an integer value of the position?

I want to use something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
     int position = recyclerView.getChildPosition(i);
}
```

obviously that is not correct. but how can I get, say, the 3rd item of the recyclerview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used:

```
View x = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It is an answer @skywinder